# How to format database data to an excel in the same row c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel

This is my table in the database

[image]

With this table, it will be export to an excel using the below format where records with the **same case_id** will be exported to the excel in the **same row**

```
Desired Output
```

[image]

Im struggling in how to make the data from database show in the ***same row*** of an excel for the ***same case_id***

Here's a snippet of excel of what im currently working on

[image]

Here's my C# Code

```
public string DB_CONN =
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getAll();
    }


    protected void getAll()
    {

        DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;
        string now_time = dTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        string sql = "";
        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        MySqlDataAdapter msda = null;
        DataSet ds = null;

        string id = "ALL";

        sql = "SELECT * FROM testing";


        conn = new MySqlConnection(DB_CONN);
        conn.Open();

        msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        msda.Fill(ds, "charge");

        using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("收入報表");

            int row = 1;

            //Add the headers

            worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = "date";
            worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = "heading";
            worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = "detail";
            worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = "heading";
            worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = "detail";
            worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = "heading";
            worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = "detail";


            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["charge"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                ++row;
                int k = 0;
                worksheet.Cells[row, ++k].Value = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["date"].ToString();


                worksheet.Cells[row, ++k].Value = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString();
                worksheet.Cells[row, ++k].Value = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["detail"].ToString();
                worksheet.Cells[row, ++k].Value = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["case_id"].ToString();

            }


            String exportFileName = "income_report_" + "_" + ".xlsx";

            Byte[] fileBytes = p.GetAsByteArray(); //Read the Excel file in a byte array

            //Clear the response
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Clear();


            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + exportFileName + "; "

            );
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the previous row is the same case id and bump the column instead of bumping the row.

```
var lastColumn;
var row = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ds.Tables["charge"].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != 0 && ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["case_id"].ToString() == ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i - 1]["case_id"].ToString())
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, lastColumn++] = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString();
        worksheet.Cells[row, lastColumn++] = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["detail"].ToString();
        continue;
    }
    row++;
    worksheet.Cells[row, 1] = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["date"].ToString();
    worksheet.Cells[row, 2] = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["heading"].ToString();
    worksheet.Cells[row, 3] = ds.Tables["charge"].Rows[i]["detail"].ToString();
    lastColumn = 3;
}
```